# Grid Not Taking Full Width

Tags: android

I recently got a new computer and installed android studio on it. Now my grid is not taking the full width of the screen. I am almost certain it was taking the full width on my other install of android studio. I do not have a device to test on but on the emulators it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="io.musicschool.app.NoteTrainerActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/intervalNoteImage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/c4" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/intervalNoteImage"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:columnCount="3"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/noteImage"

                >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/unison_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:text="Unison"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"

                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/min2nd_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="Min 2nd"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/maj2nd_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:text="Maj 2nd"
                    android:textAllCaps="false" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/min3rd_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:text="Min 3rd"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"


                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/maj3rd_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:text="Maj 3rd"
                    android:textAllCaps="false" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/per4th_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:text="Per 4th"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/aug4th_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:text="Aug 4th"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dim5th_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:text="Dim 5th"
                    android:textAllCaps="false" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/per5th_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:text="Per 5th"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/min6th_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:text="Min 6th"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/maj6th_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:text="Maj 6th"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/min7th_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:text="Min 7th"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/maj7th_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="4"
                    android:text="Maj 7th"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/oct_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="4"
                    android:text="Octave"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    />
            </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: your code is working fine on my device. Grid layout is taking full width here

Comment: I am testing with version 21 emulator. What version are you using @Umair?

Comment: I ran it on version 28. maybe cleaning or clearing cache and restarting will work.

Comment: OK Thanks will try

Comment: It is weird. In design view it shows as taking full width, and as mentioned on my previously installed android studio I swear it was taking full width. Cleaning project had no effect. Thanks